# 4.5µA Li-Ion Battery Protection Circuit

Tags: amplifier, battery-charging, power-electronics

I tried to simulate the circuit given in your design note "https://www.analog.com/en/technical-articles/battery-protection-circuit.html"

According to the designer, the cut off voltage is 3V but the circuit is not going to cut off when the i/p is below 3V also.

Please see the attached simulation result. Could you please help me how to solve this issue?

[image: simulation result]

Comment: And where is your load?

Comment: "our design note"?

Comment: Note to other readers: [The same question has been posted at the Analog Devices forum](https://ez.analog.com/amplifiers/f/q-a/103271/4-5-a-li-ion-battery-protection-circuit), so replies / updates etc. might appear there too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problems with this simulations are:

1. The circuit has no load. Use something reasonable, like 100 ohms.
2. The PFET looks wrong, try something like FDS4465.
3. Not sure what the V/V chart mean, I just applied a variable voltage V1.

[image]

Comment: Hi,it is working after connecting the load at the output.For determining the "lockout voltage" why they are not considering the VBAT. May I know why they are not writing KVL including VBAT